# TypeError: Class extends value #<BasePage> is not a constructor or null

Tags: javascript, testcafe

in BasePage.js

```
import { Selector, t } from "testcafe"

class BasePage {
    constructor(){
        this.inputFieldID = Selector('#name')
    }

    async inputValueDynamicField(value){
        await t
        .typeText(this.inputFieldID , value)
    }
}

export default new BasePage
```

in LoginPage.js

```
import BasePage from "./BasePage"

class LoginPage extends BasePage{
    constructor(){
        super()
    }

    
}

export default new LoginPage();
```

in test.js

```
import LoginPage from "../page/LoginPage";

fixture('OOP')
.page("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/")

test('Helo' , async t => {
    LoginPage.inputValueInDynamicField
})
```

after I run it, it have error TypeError: Class extends value # is not a constructor or null, so someone know this, please help me on this, thanks

Comment: `LoginPage.inputValueInDynamicField` => `new LoginPage().inputValueInDynamicField()` I guess?

Comment: yes, this is LoginPage.inputValueInDynamicField(value), but still have that error

Comment: Did you also add `new` and instantiate LoginPage by adding the parens? Edit: wait: I see you're exporting an instance. Export the class instead: `export default BasePage`

Comment: Sorry but what you mean, i have edited to export default BasePage but have new error TypeError: Class constructor BasePage cannot be invoked without 'new'

Comment: `export default BasePage;` - `export default LoginPage;` - `new LoginPage().inputValueInDynamicField()`

Comment: Sorry but it same, i have updated code in the question following your comment

Comment: Please don't apply the fix in your question, when you already have answer(s). I rolled back that last edit.

Comment: Do not use `new` anywhere except inside the `test` callback.

Comment: Hi @ChrisG, i have edited my code in the question, is that correct for you ?

Comment: Please stop editing your question applying the comments. Rolled back to previous version again.

Comment: ok, roll back again

Comment: I looked at your edit and it is still completely wrong. I did post how the lines are supposed to look in a comment, just use that as-is. No new and no () in the export lines, then instantiating in the test function using both new and (). This is not difficult. I then told you to only use `new` in the test function and you removed it everywhere.

Comment: The concept is really really simple: 1. create and export the classes 2. in your test function, create a new instance using the keyword `new` and `()` to call the constructor

Answer (score 1):

Your are exporting an *instance* of `BasePage`:

```
export default new BasePage
```

Yet you expect it to be a class that can be extended:

```
class LoginPage extends BasePage
```

So don't create an instance, but just export the class to be extended:

```
export default BasePage
```

Only apply the change to *that* line. The other export should stay as it is. Or, better, remove `new` from this line too:

```
export default LoginPage
```

And then create an instance here:

```
new loginPage().inputValueInDynamicField(t)
```

### Summary

BasePage.js

```
export default BasePage
```

LoginPage.js

```
export default LoginPage;
```

test.js

```
test('Helo' , async t => {
    new LoginPage().inputValueInDynamicField(t)
})
```

Comment: HI, I have fixed it but have new error : Class constructor BasePage cannot be invoked without 'new'

Comment: How can resolved it ?

Comment: Is that happening on a line of code that you have shared?

Comment: yes, it same, only diffrent with line export default new BasePage to export default BasePage

Comment: I am asking on *which* line you get the new error... Surely it is not on *that* line.

Comment: in the last line in BasePage , it missing 'new'

Comment: Like I said, it is impossible you get the error on the line `export default BasePage`. Please check the stack trace. Read my previous comment.